# 2007 Meeting Workspace move via content and structure not working

Tags: 2007, meeting-workspace

We are trying to move several meeting workspaces from a 5th level sub-site to a 2nd level site within the same site collection.  We know regular sites at the same or different level can be moved, but for some reason the meeting workspaces won't move.  Publishing feature is activated on the destination, and we have moved test sibling sites into different sibling sites.  Error we keep getting is:

'Site in question' cannot be moved or copied into itself or one of its subsites

Are there special permissions needed above site collection admin?  My farm admin is having better success than I am at moving things within the site collection for these workspaces.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you just need to be patient!  ~=^)

1. Move modal comes up
2. select destination
3. *** wait for modal window to post back
4. then you can click "OK" to move the actual sites